# Fastify Error: Plugin must be a function or a promise. Received: 'object'

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I have a **Node.js**(`v20.10.0`) backend server using **Fastify**(`v4.25.2`) as the framework.

I have **index.js** as an entry point

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';
const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: true,
});
import router from './src/routers/index.js';

fastify.register(router, { prefix: `/api/v1` });
try {
  await fastify.listen({ port: 4000 });
} catch (err) {
  fastify.log.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

/src/**routes**/index.js

```
import { healthCheck } from '../controllers/healthCheckController.js';

const routes = {
  '/health-check': {
    method: 'GET',
    handler: async (request, reply) => {
      return healthCheck(request, reply);
    },
  },
  // Define other routes here...
};

export default routes;
```

/src/**controllers**/healthCheckController.js

```
const healthCheck = async (request, reply) => {
  const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
  reply.send({ status: 'ok', time: currentTime });
};
export { healthCheck };
```

When running the server I am getting the error

> AvvioError [Error]: Plugin must be a function or a promise. Received: 'object'

> AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID

Error Descriptions:

```
home/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:207
    throw new AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID(typeof plugin)
          ^
AvvioError [Error]: Plugin must be a function or a promise. Received: 'object'
    at assertPlugin (/home/server/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:207:11)
    at Boot._addPlugin (/home/server/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:240:12)
    at Boot.use (home/server/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:216:25)
    at server.<computed> [as register] (/home/server/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:40:14)
    at file:///home/server/index.js:34:9
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
  code: 'AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID'
}
```

Comment: Is that all you get for the error? No stack trace?

Comment: @Pointy Updated the Question with all the stack traces I am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells the truth: `routes` is an object, so you can't `register(object)`

So you need to fix the `/src/routes/index.js` file like so:

```js
export async function routes (fastify) {

  // add the route to the fastify server:
  fastify.route({
    url: '/health-check',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: async (request) => {
      return healthCheck(request);
    },
    // Define other routes here...
  })
}

export default routes;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Manuel Spigolon for the quick response and help.